# Transaction/For update lock for an eCommerce project

Tags: mysql, mariadb, locking, transaction, php

When users want to purchase their orders, The quantity of the products should be decreased. Now I'm planning to use a Transaction and a `FOR UPDATE` lock on the products and decrease the quantity of each product.

**Laravel psudo code:**

```php
// Check quantities before entering the transaction
...

DB::transaction(function () use ($cartItems) {
    $ids = $cartItems->pluck('product_id')->toArray(); // Extract product_ids -> [50, 100, 99, ...]

    $products = Product::whereIn('id', $ids)->lockForUpdate()->get();

    // Check quantities
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
        // Find the associated product
        $product = $products->first(fn ($product) => $product->id === $item->product_id);

        // Throw an exception if the product quantity is less than the quantity of the cart item
        if ($product->quantity < $item->quantity) {
            throw new \Exception("Quantity error for Product #{$product->id}");
        }
    }

    // Decrease quantities for each product
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
        $product = $products->first(fn ($product) => $product->id === $item->product_id);
        
        // SET `quantity` = `quantity` - ?
        $product->decrement('quantity', $item->quantity);

        $product->save();
    }

    ...
});

...

// Go to paypal
```

**Why the `FOR UPDATE` lock?**
Because of race-conditions. Multiple users could order the same product at the same time while the product quantity was 1.

I tried to log sql queries of Woocommerce and some other eCommerce projects but they don't use Transactions or the `for update` lock. I also asked ChatGPT to generate the code it gave me a similar piece of code to mine.

Please correct me and my code if i'm wrong.

## Update

An update for one of the comments.

In the following code we have 3 routes.

1. `/lock-and-sleep` Selects a product with the `for update` lock then sleeps for 20 seconds.
2. `/test-without-lock` Selects the same product without a lock. (Independent)
3. `/test-with-lock` Selects the product with a `for update`. This is dependent to the first route.

```php
// Response time: 20s~
Route::get('/lock-and-sleep', function () {
    DB::transaction(function () {
        Product::where('id', 5)->lockForUpdate()->first();

        sleep(20);
    });
});

// Response time: 0.XYZms (Not Blocked)
Route::get('/test-without-lock', function () {
    Product::where('id', 5)->first();

    DB::transaction(function () {
        Product::where('id', 5)->first();
    });
});

// Response time: 20s~ (Blocked)
Route::get('/test-with-lock', function () {
    DB::transaction(function () {
        Product::where('id', 5)->lockForUpdate()->first();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little point checking quantities before entering the transaction, it will be subject to race conditions, the only check that has meaning is the one being done in the transaction under the `forUpdate` lock.

You could put the `decrement` in the same loop as the check.

`DB::transaction` handles the start of transaction, commit on exit and rollback on exception.

There should be code that saves an order in a table too right? This should be in the same transaction.

Optionally, for user experience, calculate if all the items have the right quantities and roll them up in the same error message if multiple products have insufficient amounts.

Handling paypay outside the loop means that order cancelation is a separate process.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. `START TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` are handled by the `DB::transaction` function. The ordered products are reserved for 30 minutes and are rolled back automatically (another transaction in a Cronjob) if the client doesn't complete the purchase. Does the `for update` lock block `SELECT * products ...` which are not inside transactions (Single Select Queries)?

Comment: `DB::transaction` ah, good - php not my strong point as you can tell by the answer. Single queries are still transactions, and yes, they would lock wait, until the write lock transaction is committed. If the number of items is very significant (100s) you could create a temp table of the IDs and use SQL statements with joins to lock/update rather than a loop.

Comment: I tried a select query with `for update` and delayed it for 20 seconds using `sleep(20)` inside a transaction. other select queries work perfectly fine and are not affected by the lock, even in a transaction. but if i add the `for update` lock, they wait for previous locks to be released. it's MySQL. is this behavior ok?

Comment: seems all right. Which MySQL version. Was the sleep before or after product counts where decremented.

Comment: I added my code to the question (unrelated to the main question). Btw it's not pure MySQL, it's MariaDB. `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.27-MariaDB,`

Comment: I also tested with MySQL 8.0, The same results.

Comment: MariaDB is good. Mentioning it in your question can expose new opportunties with some of its added features. Updated question to answer `DB::Transaction` construct. You're right on the locking, no effects, its an uncommitted transaction so its invisible. It will only lock when two orders have an overlap, which is what the "for update" is for. Happy databasing with MariaDB.